Can't install Ubuntu 24.04 on VirtualBox
I would like to install the new Ubuntu 24.04 on a VM with VirtualBox. I have setup the new VM by following the Ubuntu website like this:

The problem is that when I start this VM and the boot menu appears, I click on Try or Install Ubuntu and then a black screen with only a blinking white underscore character appears.
Here is the zip file with the log. I can't understand what is wrong with this machine.

Honestly i gave up trying to get this VM to work and I made a dual boot Win11/Ubuntu :) Everything is working fine without problems. Thanks all for support anyway.

Have you tried 22.04 or even 23.10?  24.04 is still new and there might be issues.  See if they work so that you can decide whether to investigate VirtualBox further or 24.04...

Which vBox version are you using? According to https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads , there are issues with bridged and host-only networks, but your config shows NAT, so that might not be the problem. Your linked logfile is gone. You better paste it here as code block, if it is not too large. If it is too large (> 300 lines, my personal opionion), reduce it in the editor.

Does this answer your question? My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?

Did you choose the base Ubuntu machine type? When I created the last one I had to enable EFI, re-add the iso file (when it shows as unattended, it's probably 0 B) and max out the video memory to 128MB, else there was just a black screen with a crosshair as cursor.

You may improve your host environment for Ubuntu 24.04 by these steps:

Get and install the latest VirtualBox
Restart your computer and check the CPU settings in BIOS: Intel VT-x or AMD-V should be enabled
Last but the most important: disable Hyper-V with the following command in an elevated PowerShell prompt:

  Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-Hypervisor


Virtualbox 7.1 had problems when I tried it. Virtualbox 7.0.20 I got installed but now I'm having video problems, making it unusable. It also hung.

I think disable Hyper-V is the most important though. Have you tried it?

updating virtualbox worked.

Installing Ubuntu 24.04 on Oracle VirtualBox is a straightforward process, ideal for exploring the latest features of Ubuntu within a virtual environment. Follow these steps to set it up:
Download Ubuntu 24.04 ISO:
Visit the official Ubuntu website and download the ISO file for Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (Long Term Support).
Install Oracle VirtualBox:
If you haven't already, download and install Oracle VirtualBox from the official website. VirtualBox is a powerful virtualization tool that allows you to run multiple operating systems on your computer.
Create a New Virtual Machine:
Open VirtualBox and click on the "New" button to create a new virtual machine. Follow the wizard, providing a name for your VM and selecting "Linux" as the type and "Ubuntu (64-bit)" as the version.
Allocate Memory:
Choose the amount of memory (RAM) to allocate to your virtual machine. Ubuntu 24.04 typically runs well with at least 2GB of RAM, but you can adjust this according to your system's resources.
Create a Virtual Hard Disk: Create a virtual hard disk for your Ubuntu VM. Choose the default options unless you have specific requirements.
Configure Settings:
Before starting the VM, you can configure additional settings such as the number of CPU cores, video memory, and enabling features like 3D acceleration.
Mount Ubuntu ISO:
In the settings of your VM, go to "Storage" and select the empty disk under "Controller: IDE." Click on the disk icon next to "Optical Drive" and choose "Choose a disk file." Select the Ubuntu 24.04 ISO file you downloaded earlier.
Start the Virtual Machine:
With the ISO mounted, start the VM. The Ubuntu installation process should begin automatically. Follow the on-screen instructions to install Ubuntu on the virtual hard disk.
Complete Installation:
Once the installation is complete, VirtualBox may prompt you to remove the installation media (the Ubuntu ISO). If not, go to the VM settings, remove the ISO from the virtual optical drive, and restart the VM.
Enjoy Ubuntu 24.04:
Your Ubuntu 24.04 virtual machine is now ready to use! Explore the new features and functionalities of Ubuntu within VirtualBox.
For a visual walkthrough of the installation process, check out this tutorial on TechTalk's YouTube channel: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2GjMQtocAsY&t=2s&ab_channel=TechTalk

I had the same issue. You see in Storage where the secondary controller says Unattended? I think this means you need to add your ISO file for Ubuntu-24.04 again.
This YT video explains how to do it:
https://youtu.be/DhVjgI57Ino?si=fKUo-CNEqB-q2aSd&t=502
The only difference is that instead of seeing "Empty" in the controller ide, you'll see a long path for the "unattended" ISO. After making that change, it should hopefully fix the issue—I know that was the solution that worked for me.
